# Breaking out of if statement and loop when condition is met

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table called ts_rounds in my database with the following structure

```
round | current
===============
P     | 0
1     | 1
2     | 0
3     | 0
4     | 0
```

I'm trying to echo a certain `<div>` arrangement in two different conditions:

1. **one current** value is 1 and the rest are 0
2. **all current** are 0, more than **one current** value is 1

Once a condition is met then I want to break out of the if statement.

This is my code so far, the first condition is met but I'm having trouble meeting the second one.

```
<div id="timeline">

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from ts_rounds";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        if ($row["round"] == "P" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    '; 
            }
        else if ($row["round"] == "1" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    ';
            } 
        else if ($row["round"] == "2" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    '; 
            }
        else if ($row["round"] == "3" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    '; 
            }
        else if ($row["round"] == "4" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    </div>'; 
            }
        else if ($row["round"] == "A" && $row["current"] == "1") {
        echo 
            '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    '; 
            }
        else {
            $rounds = '
            <div id="r0" class="circle_small">
    <h3>P</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="r1" class="circle_small"><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div id="r2" class="circle_small"><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div id="r3" class="circle_small"><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div id="r4" class="circle_small"><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div id="r5" class="circle_small"><h3>A</h3></div>
    <hr id="line">
    ';
        }
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `while` instead of `if`.

Comment: if elseif and else not requires any breaking!!! they are used for your purpose! break and continue can be used only inside loops.

Comment: PHP provides `break` and `continue`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. How do I ensure that both conditions are met in the best way?

Comment: How many records you'll be pulling from query? Meeting the condition is ambiguous.

Comment: I will be pulling 6 records

Comment: you'll be displaying all the six records too?

Comment: Yeah - with div arangements dependent on whether current is 1 or 0

Comment: What does `Once a condition is meant then I want to break out of the if statement.` what you break?

Comment: I've updated that section - I wanted it to say `once a condition is met to break out of the if statement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is something on these lines:

```
$circleSize = array ('circle_small', 'circle');
$rounds = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {

    switch ($row['round']) {
        case 'P':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r0" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>P</h3></div>';break;
        case '1':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r1" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>1</h3></div>';break;
        case '2':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r2" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>2</h3></div>';break;
        case '3':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r3" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>3</h3></div>';break;
        case '4':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r4" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>4</h3></div>';break;
        case 'A':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r5" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>A</h3></div>';break;
    }
}
echo $rounds;
```

Comment: Do I put this after `$sql = "SELECT * from ts_rounds"; $result = $pdo->query($sql);`?

Comment: It looks like this http://i.imgur.com/Q41kBnM.png but its only meant to show one row of P 1 2 3 4 5, with only one circle lit up if **current=1**. If there is more more than one circle where **current=1** or none then all circles should be grey

Comment: are you sure `SELECT * from ts_rounds` gives you only 6 records only? Did you try the above code?

Comment: This is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/5mvU8KjL and yeah it does. I've tried the above code :-)

Comment: share the resulting html page(source) together with CSS if you can.

Comment: Evidently query is returning more than 6 records. CSS shared is not matching with desired display.

Answer (score 1):

Highly repeteitive code, especially since your html is basically only trivially changed between versions. why not something more like

```
$sql = "SELECT current, round FROM yourtable"
$results = array()
while($row = fetch($result)) {
   $results[$row['current']][] = $row['round'];
}
```

That'll give you an array

```
0: p, 2, 3, 4
1: 1
```

From there the output logic becomes merely "which 0/1 value am I outputting now" to adjust the html as necessary. no need to repeat the html block 5 times for every variation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I write the array as logic to meet both conditions? I haven't done anything like this before